# How to check if character at current index in for loop is a specific character (e.g. the letter A, the number 2, etc)?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm building a simple program in Java that finds letters in strings and replaces them with a number, but I'm having trouble finding a method that will allow me to check for the exact specific character. There are plenty for digits and letters in general.

As my for loop stands now, it just replaces the letter everywhere, irregardless of whether it is within the range specified by **start** and **end**.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
String str = "A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A";
int start = 3;
int end = 9;

for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) {
        str = str.replaceAll("A", "9");
return str;
```

Expected Output:

`A.A.9.9.9.A.A.A`

Actual Output:

`9.9.9.9.9.9.9.9`

Comment: You can directly compare two characters with `==`:  `if (str.charAt(i) == 'A') { ..`

Comment: if i understand correctly, you're looking for a method to replace a specific character within a given `start` and `end` range?

Comment: Yes, and my thought was to do so by using replaceAll(), but only after an If statement checks whether the character is "A". Probably not an efficient way to do so, but I think it could work.

Comment: Once you find a character, you use `str.replaceAll` which does what it says --- it replaces *all* these characters in `str`, no matter where you found them.

Comment: If you did find the solution to your question you should accept the correct answer. So that others can be sure it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have

```
str = str.replaceAll("A", "9");
```

This will replace all the occurrences of `A` to `9`

Instead of your approach, you should

1.Convert the string to a char array

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

2.Then replace each occurrence of character with a number

```
if (Character.isLetter(charArray[i])){
    //Character Found
    charArray[i] = '9';
}
```

3. Convert it back to string using

```
str = String.valueOf(charArray);
```

Modified Code:

```
String str = "A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A";
int start = 3;
int end = 9;

//Converting String to char array
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(charArray[i])){
        //Character Found
        charArray[i] = '9';
    }
}

//Converting Back to String
str = String.valueOf(charArray);

System.out.println(charArray);

System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare for character equality and then use string builder to replace the specified character

```
//Use of StringBuffer preferred over String as String are immutable
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str); 
// -1 to start as index start from 0
for (int i = start-1; i < end; i++) {
    char currentChar = currentString.charAt(i);

    if (currentChar == "A") {
       sb.setCharAt(i, '9');
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it that way. Cut out the string to isolate the part you want to act on, do  your replace ans stitch it all back together :

```
    String str = "A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A";
    int startIndex = 3;
    int endIndex = 9;

    String beginning = str.substring(0, startIndex);
    String middle = str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    String end = str.substring(endIndex);

    middle = middle.replaceAll("A", "9");

    String result = beginning + middle + end;

    System.out.println(result);
```

Prints out :

```
A.A.9.9.9.A.A.A
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, you could do it in one line

```
String str = "A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A";
int startIndex = 3;
int endIndex = 9;

String result = 
    str.substring(0, startIndex) + 
    str.substring(startIndex, endIndex).replaceAll("A", "9") + 
    str.substring(endIndex);
```

Comment: I like this answer you can make it shorter like `str = str.substring(0, start)
                + str.substring(start, end).replaceAll("A", "9")
                + str.substring(start, str.length());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using substrings to let you choose what portion of the string you want to test

```
int start = 3;
int end = 9;
String str = "A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A";
String startStr = str.substring(0,start);
String endStr = str.substring(end);
String newStr="";
char temp=' ';
   for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
       temp = str.charAt(i);
       if (temp=='A')
            newStr+="9";
       else
            newStr += temp;
   }
return(startStr + newStr + endStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing all the match found in the string and not specifying the index that needs to be replaced.

Use the **StringBuffer** `replace` method like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String str = "AAAAAAAA";
   int start = 3;
   int end = 9;
   str = replaceBetweenIndexes(str, start, end, "9"); // AAA999AA
   str = replaceBetweenIndexes("ABCD6EFG", start, end, "3"); // ABC363FG
}

public static String replaceBetweenIndexes(String str, int start, int end, String replaceWith) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(str);
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
          if (Character.isLetter(strBuf.charAt(i)) {
             strBuf.replace(i, i+1, replaceWith);
          }
        }
        return strBuf.toString(); 
}
```